# Codeigniter- controller views using ajax and without

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, controller

I have a default controller:

class Home extends CI_Controller {

```
public function index() 
{   
    $data['content']='discover';
    $this->load->view('layouts/master', $data);             
}   

public function categories()
{
    $this->load->view('categories');
}
```

}

On click, using AJAX i was able to load the view *categories.php* and update the URL to www.mywebsite.com/categories without refreshing the page.

But now, if the user lands here directly using the link or refreshes the page he ends up loading only the *categories.php* view and not the *master.php* view

1. How do i load the master.php and categories.php view on direct URL navigation or page refresh
2. Just load categories.php when using AJAX.

My AJAX:

```
$('#navbar a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    href=$(this).attr('href');
    if (href.indexOf(document.domain) > -1 || href.indexOf(':') === -1){
        window.history.pushState('obj', '', href);
        navigat(href);          
    }       
});

function navigat(href){             
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url:href,
        cache:false,
        dataType: 'html',
        statusCode: {
                404: function() {
                  $("#content").html('Could not contact server.');
                },
                500: function() {
                  $("#content").html('A server-side error has occurred.');
                }
        },
        error: function() {
            $("#content").html('A problem has occurred.');
        },
        success: function(html) {
            $('#content').html(html);

        }
    });     
};
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CodeIgniter Input Class Provides some helper functions to deal with user inputs , this class is initialized automatically by the system so there is no need to do it manually.

I always recommend to use this class instead using PHP Core Input Variables while dealing with forms and requests.

To check Ajax Request in CodeIgniter, codeIgniter Output Class Method class is_ajax_request() , this function checks to see if the HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH server header has been set, if set response will be true otherwise false means it will returns a boolean response.

In you controller you can use below code

```
if (!$this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
        echo "Not ajax request";
} else {
        echo "Ajax Request";
}
```

Hence using the above script in your controller action you can identify whether user is coming directly or from ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
<?php echo site_url()?>
```

in the href , hope this will help you to solve the issue